# LibGDX - button change image on hover over time

Tags: libgdx, ui-design

As we all know, LibGDX has a `TextButton`class which has a `TextButtonStyle` and `ButtonStyle`. The style has some parameters:

- up - an image which is shown normally as a button background
- down - shown when the button is being 'pressed'
- over - on hover

**My question is:**
Is there any way to implement the 'hovering' / changing the background image IN TIME? So for example it takes 2 seconds and it's smooth?

I tried with actions and tween engine, but honestly, I really have no idea how I should implement this. Maybe some alpha operations?

If you have any ideas, I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extend a `TextButton`
2. Override a `draw()` method
3. Make a 'fake actor' in this new class which you'll use to a hover action
4. In `draw()` don't call super and draw the button on your own
5. Draw the 'hover' background with the 'fake actor's' alpha
6. Add alpha action to the fake actor on hover/click
7. Profit

   Example:

   ```
   public class SomeTextButton extends TextButton{

       private Actor hoverActor;

       public SomeTextButton(//some code){
       // some code
       hoverActor = new Actor();
       hoverActor.getColor().a = 0f;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentalpha){
       //super.draw() // don't! you want to draw on your own

       hoverActor.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

       // there are two backgrounds in a textfield - normal and hover
       batch.begin();


       // we draw the hover background with the fake actor's alpha
       Color oldBatchColor = batch.getColor();
       Color newColor = new Color(batch.getColor());
       newColor.a = hoverActor.a;

       hoverbackground.draw(batch, this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

       batch.setColor(oldBatchColor);

       // we draw the normalbackground normally, without any alpha magic
       normalBackground.draw(batch, this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

       batch.end();
   }

   public Actor getHoverActor(){
       return hoverActor;
   }
   ```

}

To fire it:

```
SomeTextButton button = new SomeTextButton(// some params);
stage.add(button);

button.addListener(new HoverListener(){
    onHover(){
        button.getHoverActor().addAction(Actions.alpha(1f,1f)); // profit
    }
});
```

Comment: From where this HoverListener comes ? I can't find it anywhere.